# How to fix InveDisplayInventory.cs(37,50): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'TextMeshProUGUI' could not be found?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to use TextMeshProUGUI in my code, but I am getting this error:

> Assets-Scriptable Objects\Inventory\DisplayInventory.cs(37,50): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'TextMeshProUGUI' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Which I am using `using UnityEngine.UI;`.

My code:

```
 _slot.Key.GetComponentInChildren<TextMeshProUGUI>().text = _slot.Value.amount == 1 ? "" : _slot.Value.amount.ToString("n0");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `using TMPro;` since `TextMeshProUGUI` is defined in that namespace.